# CSS floats 'boxes' layout different sized boxes

Tags: css, css-float

I am trying to sort out this layout using CSS and floating the divs.
There are standard sized boxes a large box and a tall box.
This is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NhWjm/)

I have this markup -

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .boxesHolder 
    {   width:970px;
        border:1px solid green;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        background-color:#06C;}
    .boxes
    {   border:1px solid blue;  
        margin:5px; 
        background-color:#FFF;}

    .stand {width:230px; height:180px;}
    .large {width:474px; height:372px;}
    .tall { width:230px height:372px;}
    .fLeft{float:left;}
    .fRight{float:right;}
    .clear {clear:both;}

    </style>
 </head>

 <body>

    <div class = "boxesHolder">

        <div class = "boxes stand fLeft">1</div>
        <div class = "boxes stand fRight">3</div>
        <div class = "boxes large fRight">2</div>
        <div class = "boxes stand fLeft">4</div>
        <div class = "boxes stand fLeft">5</div>
        <div class = "boxes stand fLeft">6</div>
        <div class = "boxes stand fLeft">7</div>

    <div class ="clear"></div>
    </div>

 </body>
```

I cant post an image of the layout as I've got no reputation points yet...

I just want to add the tall box in the space bottom right. I just cant work it out.
Should I do it with absolutely positioned boxes? What is the best approach. Would have been easy with a table layout!

Comment: Where is the tall box in the html?

Comment: What he needs is to get a box div 8 in the right bottom corner.

Comment: Thanks, the tall box is missing because I don't know where to put it. Tall box class .tall needs to go in the space.

Comment: If you don't require different variations of this grid setup, you can tweak it by setting a negative top margin. As you can see something else's not right on your demo: the margin of the second box under the large ones is one px too short. If you want different variations, you're better off looking at existing alternatives like [gridster.js](http://gridster.net/).

Comment: If you find yourself thinking, "This would be easy with tables", try adding another layer of divs that are immediate children of .boxesHolder that are "columns" (floated divs), with the .boxes then floated (as necessary) inside those.  The layout still will not necessarily be displayed as ordered in the HTML, but it doesn't appear that you care about that from your current markup, and you will be able to get it to look the way you want.

Comment: Thanks BjornJohnson that looks like the best way to me. Thanks Tyblitz gridster looks pretty awesome as well. @BjornJohnson

Answer (score 0):

Try This: http://jsfiddle.net/fCc5d/1/

And here is the html:

```
<div class = "boxesHolder">

        <div class = "boxes stand fRight">1</div>
        <div class = "boxes stand fRight">3</div>        
        <div class = "boxes stand fRight">4</div>
        <div class = "boxes stand fRight">5</div>
        <div class = "boxes large fRight">2</div>
        <div class = "boxes stand fRight">6</div>
        <div class = "boxes stand fRight">7</div>
        <div class = "boxes stand fRight">8</div>
        <div class = "boxes stand fRight">9</div>

    <div class ="clear"></div>
 </div>
```

You can change the numbers as you want.

Comment: Cheers Gimmy - its not quite what I was looking for. On my example there's a missing tall div on the bottom right. That needs to be the .tall class. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/NhWjm/). I think this is best done by having extra outer divs for columns which are floated as per @BjornJohnson

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to achieve something like this ?
http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/fvzaF/
If yes , then you'll need to mixed float left/right/none and display (not block) 
and dispatch them clearly from style sheet.

```
  .boxesHolder {
       width:970px;
       border:1px solid green;
       margin-left:auto;
       margin-right:auto;
       background-color:#06C;
   }
   .boxes {
       border:1px solid blue;
       margin:5px;
       background-color:#FFF;
   }
   .stand {
       width:230px;
       height:180px;
   }
   .large {
       width:474px;
       height:372px;
   }
   .tall {
       width:230px height:372px;
   }
   .fLeft {
       float:left;
   }
   .fRight {
       float:right;
       clear:right
   }
   .clear {
       clear:both;
   }
   div div:before {
       content:attr(class);
   }
   div:nth-child(4), div:nth-child(5) {
       float:none;
       display:inline-block;
       margin:5px 3px;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works - adds 3 column divs that are floated left, the boxes divs inside. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tuftini/EbfCs/)

```
 <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .boxesHolder 
    {   width:928px;
        border:1px solid green;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        background-color:#06C;
        padding:5px;}
    .boxes
    {   border:1px solid red;   
        background-color:#FFF;
        margin:0px;}

    .stand {width:230px; height:180px;}
    .large {width:462px; height:362px;}
    .tall { width:230px; height:362px;}
    .fLeft{float:left;}
    .clear {clear:both;}


    </style>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div class = "boxesHolder">

        <div class = "col fLeft">
            <div class = "boxes stand"></div>
            <div class = "boxes stand"></div>
            <div class = "boxes stand"></div>
        </div>

        <div class = "col fLeft">
            <div class = "boxes large"></div>
            <div class = "boxes stand fLeft"></div>
            <div class = "boxes stand fLeft"></div>
        </div>

        <div class = "col fLeft">
            <div class = "boxes stand"></div>
            <div class = "boxes tall"></div>
        </div>


    <div class ="clear"></div>
    </div>


    </body>
```